# WPF - create a grid of colors

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, colors, grid

I have a ViewModel in WPF that looks something like this:

```
public class SwatchViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Color> Colors { get; private set; }
}
```

I want to display each of the colors in the collection, laying them out in columns. Each of the columns should take up the same amount of space in the control and all columns combined should fill the width of the control. The control can be sized arbitrarily.

So if `Colors` contained `{ Colors.Red, Colors.Green, Colors.Blue }` then I would want three columns, each taking up a third of the width of the control, with each column colored appropriately.

What is the best way of doing this? It seems suited for an `ItemsControl` except for the fact an `ItemsControl` doesn't stretch its items to fill the available width... that's a job for the `Grid`... but grid's columns can't be bound....

XAML is preferred, though I'm quite happy to fall back to C# if necessary.

Comment: Are you interested in Selection behavior also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `UniformGrid`. A uniform grid suits your needs exactly, it adds cells according to the number of children it contains.

Example:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="..." ItemTemplate="...">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Setting `Rows` to `1` constrains the row count to 1 (duh...).